# Get the image ID of the Clicked image in silverlight Deep Zoom?

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom

I am in designing the site something like hardrock memorabilia using slverlight DeepZoom.. And i have managed to create dynamic static image lists and it was working fine with all the zoom & Pan features..

But i wanted get the  id or name of the clicked image to display the Information balloon around the selected image.. (Kind of highglighting)... Based on the image id i will hit the DB and get the image dtails..

can somebody help me out this???

,

Comment: like how to retrieve the associated tag info of theselected image??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to achive this one.. and i have explained this here..  [how-to-add-graphics-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270480/how-to-add-graphics-on-top-of-a-multiscaleimage/1270664#1270664)