# How to add graphics on top of a multiscaleimage?

Tags: .net, graphics, silverlight-3.0, multiscaleimage

I want to add graphics to a multiscaleimage. I use the project that Deep Zoom Composer auto generated when creating a multiscaleimage. Displaying the multiscaleimage from VS2008 works.

I've tried this and added the graphics to the maincanvas, without any results:

```
<Grid>
 <Canvas Name="maincanvas"/>
 <MultiScaleImage/>
</Grid>
```

Edit: When the user zooms in on the multiscaleimage, the user can place geometrically figures on the image. E.g. place a rectangle next to a person in the image, which will act as a speech balloon. I know this can be done on the image before the image is scaled, but I would like to do it dynamically.

Comment: can u be more speciific.. u wanted to add a graphic item on top of the selected image... or all the loaded images??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the tutorial at [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901589%28VS.95%29.aspx), and then using the following code, made it possible to draw on top of the multiscaleimage.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<MultiScaleImage x:Name="deepZoomObject" Source="source/dzc_output.xml"/>  
<Canvas>
 <Line X1="10" Y1="100" X2="80" Y2="30" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="20" Canvas.Top="-16" Canvas.Left="238"></Line>
</Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to draw the grpahics over the particular image, first u need to find out the co-odrinates of the multiscale image..Am not sure abt reading co-ordinates of all the images in mutliscale canvass image... but there is a way you can do it on user selected image...

project silverlights [wilfred](http://projectsilverlight.blogspot.com/2008/04/deep-zoom-highlight-clicked-subimage.html) posted an interesting article abt picking the selected multiscale item and its co-ordinates..

And there is a dedicated forum for [deepzoom](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/deepzoomcomposer/threads).. its very active one.. you can try that too..